# Cannot connect to Cassandra in Docker, getting "Unable to connect to any servers" with cqlsh

Tags: docker, pyspark, cassandra, airflow, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to build a containerized mini batch data processing pipeline using PySpark and Docker after which the processed data would be stored in Cassandra. I am utilizing a docker-compose file for pulling the images for spark and Cassandra, I am able to run my pyspark file without errors, however I have erros when trying to run the cassandra lines such as creating keyspace and tables which is why I tried to use cqlsh in the container after which I got the following error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', { \
  '127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to \
  [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

docker commands: -

```
docker compose up -d

docker ps 

docker exec -it container-id cqlsh: I get the error after this command
```

I have tried pulling various types of Cassandra images which comes up with the same error and I have checked several sources to identify how to schedule this using airflow in the container to no avail

I used the following docker-compose: -

````
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge


services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    volumes: 
    - ".:/opt/spark"
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    networks:
      - app-tier

    
  cassandra:
    image: 'bitnami/cassandra:latest'
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/cassandra:4.1
    #image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '127.0.0.1:9042:9042'
    volumes:
      #- 'cassandra_data:/bitnami'
      - ".:/opt/cassandra"
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    networks:
      - app-tier ```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908017/cannot-connect-to-local-datastax-cassandra-running-in-docker/63908894#63908894, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799167/contact-points-for-a-local-cassandra-instance/54813669#54813669

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlexOtt, I have read through the thread and I inferred that "I need to specify the IP address of your machine instead of localhost (is this correct)". I would like to ask if I will specify this address in the docker-compose file? I am relatively new to docker.

Comment: you can use names of containers ...

Comment: @AlexOtt, I found this in a website, do you mean adding something like it?

` ` ` 
environment:
      DB_UPSTREAM: http://${DOCKER_GATEWAY_HOST:-host.docker.internal}:3000
` ` `

Comment: maybe, I haven't used docker-compose for a while

Comment: Why did you used this 
     - '127.0.0.1:9042:9042' line??
port mapping  you can mention 
- 19042:9042 
Your question don't have clarity on why did you have chosen to use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your insights @PavanDevarakonda. I noticed that the image utilized 127.0.0.1 which is why I stated it explicitly, I ended up using 9042:9042. I have been able to get cqlsh to work (apparently, I didn't cd to the location of cqlsh.exe using **cd opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin** after which I used command **cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra** after which I am able to create keyspaces and tables but with issues: 
1. I am unable to view the cluster on my host machine localhost port
2. My script to execute cql queries generates no erros but noting happens in cassandra, no keyspaces and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers run in their own network so when you connect to a container, you need to specify the network to connect to.

In your case, you've named the network `app-tier` so specify the network in your command with `--network app-tier`.

Additionally, you also need to specify the name of the container you're connecting to. You can find out the container's name from the `docker ps` output.

If you're interested, the [Quickstart Guide](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html) on the official Apache Cassandra website has detailed steps for running Cassandra in Docker.

Finally, I'd highly recommend you spend some time learning Docker first so you understand the basics. Otherwise, you will be wasting a lot of time running into other simple issues unrelated to Cassandra or Spark. Cheers!